# get selecteditem of a treeview in wpf

Tags: wpf, treeview

I am trying to access file name from treeview selected item. How can I access Header field from object to.[image]

Code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = Directory1.SelectedValue.ToString();//.ToStrin();
            Object to = Directory1.SelectedValue;
            Directory1.Items.ToString();
            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            string sourceFile = args[1] + "\\" + fileName;
            string destpath = args[2] + "\\" + fileName;

            if (File.Exists(destpath))
            {
                File.Delete(destpath);
            }
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destpath);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cast the SelectedValue to TreeViewItem. Try this:

```
string MyHeader = ((TreeViewItem)Directory1.SelectedValue).Header.ToString();
```